# ID variable from URL

Tags: php, url

Ok so when somebody types this into the URL `mywebsite.com/?s1=affiliateid`

I want to take the `affiliateid` part out of the URL. Every affiliate will put a different username into the address.

Then I want to create a link will point to `differentwebsite.com/?id=affiliateid` based on the username typed into the address bar.

Now so far, I know that I have to have something like this will get that affiliate id

```
$aff_id = $_GET['s1'];
```

Then I can use that variable to create a link or just redirect it to the next page

```
differentwebsite.com/?id=$aff_id
```

My question is, where do I place this code at? `$aff_id = $_GET['s1'];`

Do I have to make a page called `?s1.php` or something?

Comment: Isn't this method prone to SQL Injection?

Comment: `mywebsite.com/?s1=affiliateid` is a shortcut for `mywebsite.com/index.php?s1=affiliateid` so the code should be in index.php

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `s1` isn't used anywhere else but just to create a link:

```
<?php
  $s1 = isset($_GET['s1']) && !empty($_GET['s1'])
      ? $_GET['s1'] // it's populated, use the passed value
      : '';         // default value in case it's not present

  //
  // Maybe check $s1 is indeed valid
  //

  $newurl = sprintf('http://differentwebsite.com/?id=%s', urlencode($_GET['s1']));
?>
```

Then you can output that link somewhere on the page, like:

```
<a href="<?= $newurl; ?>">New Url Here</a>
```

[`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php) will make sure that if `s1` has characters like `&`, `=`, `?`, `/` (or others) it won't break the integrity of the url.

If you want the concise approach:

```
<a href="http://differentwebsite.com/?id=<?= urlencode($_GET['s1']); ?>">
  New Url Here
</a>
```

Comment: Your method works best, I would suggest making sure the param passed in meets data type requirements if there are any. I come from Coldfusion where common practice is to define URL params with default values before they are required in case nothing is passed in. PHP is a bit more loose.

Comment: This looks like a very good method. I'm pasting it but nothing is working though... The link is creating a bunch of characters following the ID. I think you're onto something though.

Comment: urlencode will convert any non-alphanumeric characters in the 's1' param to '%XX'. You can try doing "<?= $_GET['s1']; ?>" if you want to echo what you entered in, but urlencode is standard practice when parsing values using URL. It assumes that http://differentwebsite.com/ will decode the '%XX' characters.

Answer (score 0):

Append the $aff_id that you get from mywebsite.com to the url of the new web site. Presumably, $newurl = "differentwebsite.com/?id=".$aff_id.

Edit:

> Do I have to make a page called ?s1.php or something?

You need to make a page that the user will land on when they hit the url: www.mywebsite.com/

I assume you are running a web server that can process PHP code. The code can go into a file called index.php in your server's document root directory. If you don't know what this is, I suggest googling a "how to" guide for your specific server.

Get the value of "s1" from the url and store it in $aff_id:

```
$aff_id = $_GET['s1'];
```

If you want to pass this variable into another web site which accepts an "id" parameter, then you can simply append $aff_id to the new web URL and redirect the user there.

Redirect the user to differentwebsite.com and also sends the $aff_id from mywebsite.com to the other URL:

```
header('Location: http://www.differentwebsite.com/?id='.$aff_id);
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a huge php newbie and I understand what y'all are saying but then again I'm not... could you spell out the steps for me?

Comment: I've added a bit more detail to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could place `$aff_id = $_GET['s1']` anywhere before you want to use `$aff_id`. I tend to put stuff like that at the top of the page.

Or, simply put. `"differentwebsite.com/?id=$_GET['id']"`

I would suggess you do a check to see if the id parameter exists in the URL before you try to use it. Maybe even make sure it is the data type you expect, integer, string, etc. So as when you redirect users, you don't send them somewhere else in a broken way.

If you are not using this for SQL then no SQL Injection could occur @BlackHatShadow.